# Iterative Dict Merging Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to add a key value pair from one dict to another. It sounds quite simple, but the complexity of the dicts are very different. For context I have built two dicts by parsing two data files using the python modules `json` and `csv`. The `json` dict is complex, having multiple levels, whereas my `tsv` dict is a simple dict of key:value pairs. Let me slice them each at index 1 to illustrate this:

```
json_data['objects']['counties']['geometries'][1]
>> {'arcs':[[4,5,6,7,8,9]], 'id':30105, 'type': 'Polygon'}
```

Well, I guess I can't slice the tsv dict at 1, but an example slice is:

```
tsv_data[30105]
>>'Valley'
```

Note my tsv keys are integers, and the indexing of the two dicts are different, In fact `len(tsv_data) != len(json_data[et all])`. But it's ok. My goal is to merge them in such a way that I add a name property as a key value pair to the json file, like this:

```
json_data['objects']['counties']['geometries'][1]
>> {'arcs':[[4,5,6,7,8,9]], 'id':30105, 'type': 'Polygon', 'name':'Valley'}
```

I copied a single slice to test the waters:

```
json_data_subset = copy.copy(json_data['objects']['counties']['geometries'][1])
json_data_subset['name'] = tsv_data[json_data_subset['id']]
>> {'arcs':[[4,5,6,7,8,9]], 'id':30105, 'type': 'Polygon', 'name':'Valley'}
```

So as you can see, in this case it worked. So I thought I was on the right track and proceeded to iterate:

```
j = json_data['objects']['counties']['geometries']
for i in j:
    j[i]['name'] = tsv_data[j[i]['id']]
```

But that gave me the:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict.

Yet it worked in the case above, I'm not sure why it changed its tune.

What can I do to iterate and merge the dicts, like I have done with the single slice case?

For clarity, what I'm trying to do is with that for loop is find the corresponding id number within the `tsv` file using the `id` key of the `json` file. From that I can retrieve the matching name from the `tsv`, which I then want to plug in to the `json` file as `'name':'Name of Value'`. I'm pretty sure this is one of the best ways to do it, given I don't have sequentially or matching orders between the dicts. If I'm wrong about that, feel free to suggest a better way.

**Edit:**

For the purposes of examining my exact case, I will provide my code for creating the dicts and the links to the `json` and the `tsv`. That way, you can simply copy and paste to see exactly what's going on under the hood.

```
import json
with open('us.json') as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)

import csv
with open('us-county-names.tsv') as f:
    tsv_obj = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    tsv_data = {int(rows[0]):rows[1] for rows in tsv_obj}
```

[link](https://gist.github.com/diggetybo/ca9d3c2fed76ddc7185cf966a65b8718) to json and tsv (a little large, but not overkill)

Comment: You don't show your data, so I can't say for certain what is going on. You should create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Good point, I have provided the relevant lines of code and the full data set for robustness. It can be sampled down if need be I suppose.

Comment: Well that example was not Minimal, but at least it was Complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem your facing is due to the fact that `j` is not a `dict`, it is a `list`.  You need something more like:

```
j = json_data['objects']['counties']['geometries']
for i in j:
    name = tsv_data.get(i['id'])
    if name is None:
        print('id %d not found' % i['id'])
    else:
        i['name'] = tsv_data[i['id']]
```

Comment: Oh, that explains it. I guess when I took a slice of the data it was a dict. But to do that across the whole json, it's not a dict of dicts, it's a list of dicts. Thank you for looking into this and showing me a better way. It probably would have never dawned on me otherwise.

Comment: @ArashHowaida, you are welcome.  This is why we encourage you to build an MCVE.  If you had taken the time to cut your dataset down to a postable size, you probably would have noticed the the fact that it was a list, and would have solved your own problem, simply by trying to build an MCVE to share.  But even if you don't notice.  Posting that MCVE will get you better answers faster.  Cheers.

Comment: One additional hang up I ran into was in the line `name=` line. It's saying `i['id']` is an int and not iterable. Although sometimes it ran fine. For example I got the diagnostic string: id 8014 not found. Did the int error happen to you?

Comment: The only error I had was the lack of an ID, which is why I added the `if name is None`.  Suggest you do something similar for this problem data and log or print it to try and debug.